# Were the friends of Job, who came to him when he was in pain, of another religion?

Tags: job

Friends came to Job during his pain and did stay with him for days and nights.
(Book of Job)

**But who were they? Were they of the same religion and faith as Job?**

God said that their advice was wrong and that Job should give an offering for their sins. That might tell us that they where of the same religion, but the Jews did also offer for the sins of the nations (70 nations), so not sure.

(In the Talmud it says they did travel from far away to meet Job.)

Comment: People, including Israelites, did not typically deny the existence of other gods at that time, and within the book there's no indication Job's friends were devotees of other gods. All the characters of the story attribute sovereignty to Yahweh, but argue over what that means for Job's situation. As far as 'religion' was a concept at that time, they belonged to the same one.

Comment: @MarkEdward This is the essence of a good answer. Why not migrate it to the Answer form and perhaps expand on it?

Answer (score 1):

Scripture is not clear, giving us not only preciously few details on Job’s friends, but on Job himself.  Apart from telling us he was from the East (East of what?  How far to the East?), it does not tell us when he lived, nor even when the book itself was composed.

The only hints we have are sketchy circumstantial ones: their names and elements of cultural context, such as customs, material descripions &c.  But even that could easily have been adapted from an older original story, as for instance Adam and Eve names could be Hebrew translations (or evolutions) of their original names in humankind’s universal prediluvian language.

The Talmud is largely irrelevant to Christian opinion, specially on something presumably so much older than itself; it is not authoritative, it is known to contain much incorrect information, sometimes even as anti-Christian polemics.

In Ancient times there were hardly religions as organised, doctrinal systems as we understand them; polytheism was the norm, and it was hardly distinguishable from animism.

What is obvious is that they had at least a concept of Yahweh related to the one Job (and his chronicler) held.  So, yes, it seems that they had more or less the same ‘religion & faith’ as Job.

Answer (score 0):

Since Job is pre-Abrahamic, the people in the story should be seen in the context of polytheism. While a belief among all of Job’s counselors seems to be that Yahweh is the One True God, some of them bring a false “wisdom” that they learned in their own religious context- there is a Karmic aspect to the advice of his counselors.

The voice in the narrative that ends up truly belonging to God simply teaches Job to acknowledge his position before God and trust in him for deliverance from suffering. The narration reveals that regardless of context, it is written to an audience that expects (and perhaps eagerly awaits) the One True God to arrive and speak for himself.

Answer (score -4):

Of course they believed in the same God!

The most Righteous man on Earth would not be a friend to Devil-Worshippers!

The problem was that no one knew very much about God at that time.

The Purpose of this Trial (I say,) was that Job attain Enlightenment, and permanently disenfranchise Satan.

This Job failed to do.

This would have proven to God that Man would never strain The Truth by themselves, therefore prompting Him to deploy His Covenant-making Protocol.

Comment: Welcome! We're glad you are here, but this answer would be much stronger if you showed, with sources, that it doesn't merely reflect your opinion.  I hope you'll take a minute to review [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576), and better understand how [your answer can be supported](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/692/21576).

Comment: If no one is friends to devil worshippers, then how will they hear the gospel? How will they see the gospel lived out?